# I'm getting 'error: exceeds block gas limit' despite my gas limit being very low

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs-tx

I am trying to create a simple transaction in the Rinkeby testnet using Web3.js, Ethereumjs-tx, and an Alchemy node.
I've only managed to push transactions through at 0.001 Gwei in gas and it's been pending for over an hour.
Here is a TxHash: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xdd9e7673ca54a8c4b034f214a85027f246584c21478f3143e024999bce38ffa8

I can send via MetaMask instantly for 1.5 Gwei in gas, but putting even a 0.01 Gwei gasPrice in my program throws a 'exceeds block gas limit' error. The wallets have enough Gwei in them. I don't know what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('MyAlchemyHTTPKeyForRinkeby');

const account1 = 'PublicKey1';
const account2 = 'PublicKey2'
      
const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('MyPrivateKey1', 'hex');
const privateKey2 = Buffer.from('MyPrivateKey1', 'hex');



web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account2, (err, txCount)=> {
    const txObject = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        to: account1,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1000000', 'gwei')) ,
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1.5', 'gwei')),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'gwei')),
        from: account2
    }

    //sign
    const tx = new Tx(txObject,{chain:4});
    tx.sign(privateKey2);


    const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize();
    const raw = "0x" + serializedTransaction.toString('hex');

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash)=> {
        console.log('txHash:', txHash);
        console.log('error:', err);
    })

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what gas is.

It is not a value in Wei, it is a measurement unit of its own, related to the computational cost of the various instructions supported by the EVM. 1 gas is not equal to X wei or anything, it is simply one gas.

By looking at [Etherscan Rinkeby](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/blocks) we can see that at the time of writing [this block](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/block/9645547) has a gas limit of 30,000,000 GAS (not wei). While you are providing 1.5 gwei converted to wei so : 1,500,000,000 wei that you use as a vale in gas. so you are indeed way above the block gas limit.

A simple transfer from EOA to EOA should cost 21,000 gas (feel free tro bumb this value up a little to be safe : 60,000 or so is more than enough).

The current gasPrice seem to be slightly above 1 Gwei.

So those settings should do it for you :

```
gasLimit: 60000,
gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('1.1', 'gwei')),
```

If you want something a bit more robust, do not hesitate to use gas price helpers such as [the one included in Web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getgasprice), while the gas used by your tx will be constant the gas price is not.

You could give a look to the EIP-1559 gas price mechanism as in [this documentation](https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/guides/eip-1559/send-tx-eip-1559) from Alchemy.

> I've only managed to push transactions through at 0.001 Gwei in gas
> and it's been pending for over an hour.

The tx you linked has a gas price of 0.01 Gwei, so it is way too low to be picked up by "miners". Less than 1% of the current price... no wonder why it is pending indefinitely.

Hope that answers your question !